# How to turn off AxisAngleRotation3D animation in code behind? wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have the following animation

```
AxisAngleRotation3D rotation = (AxisAngleRotation3D)Template.FindName(rotationName, this);
        DoubleAnimation angleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        angleAnimation.From = 0.0d;
        angleAnimation.To = _currentAngle;
        angleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0,3 );           


                    rotation.BeginAnimation(AxisAngleRotation3D.AngleProperty, angleAnimation);
```

Is there a way to skip to the end of the animation immediately, that is effectively removing the animation once I start it using BeginAnimation() call? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the current animation by calling again, with null:

```
rotation.BeginAnimation(AxisAngleRotation3D.AngleProperty, null);
```

Use that in the case that you need to show the animation for some amount of time, and terminate it early (or ensure that it has stopped before applying another animation).

However, if all you are trying to do is rotate your UIElement without displaying an animation, then don't use an animation at all -- just set the property directly.

Comment: That works...so I marked it as an answer...but theres a slight lag..which i am not sure how to avoid...SkipTofill() method avoids that lag or jittery appearance in the beginning...Any ideas?

Comment: @user1202434 Just as an update, I'm trying to setup a project to reproduce your lag issue. Have you tried setting up a Storyboard and controlling the animation there, instead of through BeginAnimation on the UIElement?  Wondering if that will have different behavior.